# How to implement netty Future.sync()?

Tags: netty

This is the documentation of io.netty.util.concurrent.Future:

```
Future<V> sync() throws InterruptedException
Waits for this future until it is done, and rethrows the cause of the failure if this future failed.
```

When implementing an own future that derives from the netty future I came accross this question: How do I rethrow the exception? Is there a throws declaration missing (for example throws Throwable or throws ExecutionException)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you never need to implement `Future` from scratch. There are already some existing implementations to let you use `Future` by a more friendly way.

For example, you can use a [`Promise`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/Promise.html) which is just a `Future` where you have control of this lifecycle by setting a value or an exception (similar to [`CompletableFuture` of Java8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)). Or also a [`DefaultProgressivePromise`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultProgressivePromise.html) for simulate a progression of an operation. Etc.

I can't imagine an use case of you need to rewrite a future from scratch, and it seems to me this is a bad practice.

Comment: You can also use [`ctx.executor().newPromise()`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor.html#newPromise()) to get a `Promise`, or [`ctx.executor().newProgressivePromise()`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor.html#newProgressivePromise()) to get a `ProgressivePromise`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but of course I'm hoping someone can answer my question. I can have a look into the implementation of Promise